# HTTP server is requested a domain it doesn't host. What to reply?

Tags: web-server, http

I'm trying to create a web server using node.js, (just as a learning project, not to be used in production, I know of expressjs), and I'm not sure what to do in the case I mentioned in the title?

I've tried to find a HTTP code to indicate this error (4XX?) but there doesn't seem to be any? How do production servers reply to this?

If I ask the server hosting google.com for asdasdas.com, it replies with a 404, but some other servers just redirect you to the domain they are hosting, so I'm really not too sure which option I should implement!

Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think any status code exists for that specific purpose. I agree that the 4xx codes would be the most obvious location to look for such a status code.

Clients are not supposed to be producing such requests, which is why I the 4xx class of status codes seem appropriate. Most requests matching the criteria you describe are generated by bots, often with the intend to send spam URLs to your logfiles through a referer header.

Both the 404 status code and a redirection seem like sensible options.

One argument in favor of a redirection is that in case a legitimate user ends up generating one of those requests, you still want them to visit your site. Likewise for legitimate crawlers you usually want them to find your site.

One argument in favor of a 404 is that it might reduce the traffic you get from abusers, and it will make it harder for abusers to find your real domain.

The closest match I could find in the [official list of status codes](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml) is the 421 status code introduced in HTTP/2.0.

Status code 421 is intended for cases where a connection is reused for multiple requests, but where later requests cannot be served by the same server, and the client has to retry with a new connection.

This can for example be relevant if multiple domains resolve to the same IP address, but the server infrastructure proxies incoming connections to different servers depending on the hostname. This is not exactly the same as your scenario, so I would not advice you to use 421 for your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer! :)

I think I will end up implementing the redirection, but will leave the question open for a bit in case some else wants to give their view.